# Quine-McCluskey algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to write the [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) in python, but I wanted to see if there were any versions out there that I might use instead. A google search showed few useful results. I'm looking for 4x4 map reduction, not 2x2 or 3x3. Any ideas or references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Wikipedia of which you gave the link, there are some "External links" at the bottom, among which are these, interesting relatively to your project:

- [**"** *Python Implementation by Robert Dick* **"**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/qm/0.2)

  Wouldn't this fulfil your need ?
- **"** *A series of two articles describing the algorithm(s) implemented in R: [first article](http://www.compasss.org/files/WPfiles/Dusa2007.pdf) and [second article](http://www.compasss.org/files/WPfiles/Dusa2007a.pdf). The R implementation is exhaustive and it offers complete and exact solutions. It processes up to 20 input variables.* **"**

  You could use the [**rpy** Python interface](http://baoilleach.blogspot.com/2007/11/using-r-from-python-best-of-both-worlds.html) to R language to run the R code of the Quine-McCluskey algorithm. Note that there is a rewrite of rpy : **rpy2**

  Also, why not, write yourself a new Python script, using the enhancement of the algorithm  done by Adrian Duşa in 2007 , lying in the [second article](http://www.compasss.org/files/WPfiles/Dusa2007a.pdf) ?

Comment: vi is up, and I'm coding my heart out, thanks to the reference to that second article. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
def combine(m, n):
    a = len(m)
    c = ''
    count = 0
    for i in range(a): 
        if(m[i] == n[i]):
            c += m[i]
        elif(m[i] != n[i]):
            c += '-'
            count += 1

    if(count > 1): 
        return None
    else:            
        return c


def find_prime_implicants(data):
    newList = list(data)
    size = len(newList)
    IM = []
    im = []
    im2 = []
    mark = [0]*size
    m = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(i+1, size):
            c = combine( str(newList[i]), str(newList[j]) )
            if c != None:
                im.append(str(c))
                mark[i] = 1
                mark[j] = 1
            else:
                continue

    mark2 = [0]*len(im)
    for p in range(len(im)):
        for n in range(p+1, len(im)):
            if( p != n and mark2[n] == 0):
                if( im[p] == im[n]):
                    mark2[n] = 1


    for r in range(len(im)):
        if(mark2[r] == 0):
            im2.append(im[r])

    for q in range(size):
        if( mark[q] == 0 ):
            IM.append( str(newList[q]) )
            m = m+1

    if(m == size or size == 1):
        return IM
    else:
        return IM + find_prime_implicants(im2)


minterms = set(['1101', '1100', '1110', '1111', '1010', '0011', '0111', '0110'])

minterms2 = set(['0000', '0100', '1000', '0101', '1100', '0111', '1011', '1111'])

minterms3 = set(['0001', '0011', '0100', '0110', '1011', '0000', '1000', '1010', '1100', '1101'])

print 'PI(s):', find_prime_implicants(minterms)

print 'PI2(s):', find_prime_implicants(minterms2)

print 'PI3(s):', find_prime_implicants(minterms3)
```

Comment: Does this algorithm only calculates the prime implicates or also the essential prime implicates?

Comment: @HighwayJohn: Whatever comes out, it's certainly not minimal; I have a 10-bit example with 149 ones, where the algorithm here boils it down to 137 summands, but where I know the upper limit for a minimized sum is 119.